# exporting a project in rubymine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I've created a project and now want to export it to another folder so I can do work on it. The project itself is a repository so thats why I don't just want to copy and paste the files (since I'll get the hidden .git files with it).
Is there a simple way to export a project in rubymine?

Answer (score 0):

If you use GitHub you could push all current files to your repo, then (assuming you are on a *nix command line) mkdir and/or cd into the NEW folder that you want to work in. You could then perform a:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:username/projectyouwanttomove.git
```

Let me know if that helps or not.

Comment: currently the files are hosted on a private server at our university. git.cs.mtsu.edu

Would it be the same concept as what you  suggested? git clone @git.cs.mtsu.edu/username/project.git?